# Swift skip current song playing on iPhone

Tags: swift, iphone, spotify, mpmusicplayercontroller

I would like to display info and skip the current song being played by the iPhone. I understand MPMusicPlayerController can do this for apple music. However, I would like to display and skip the current song if it is being played by a third-party app like Spotify or Audible.

Answer (score 0):

`let audioPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`

next song
`audioPlayer.skipToNextItem()`

previous song
`audioPlayer.skipToPreviousItem()`

Comment: Will this skip Spotify? In my tests, this is not the case.

Comment: For Spotify
previous song :- `appRemote?.playerAPI?.skip(toPrevious: defaultCallback)`
next song  :- `appRemote?.playerAPI?.skip(toNext: defaultCallback)`